# How to align two rasters of exact same cell size, extent in ArcGIS DEsktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster

I have two raster datasets. One is already georeferenced.
The second one is not georeferenced but should have the exact same extent and cell size as the first one. It is supposed to exactly overlap the first one.

Is there an easy way to have the second raster adopt the same georeferencing information as the first one?

This is all in ArcGIS 10.

I should add that the second raster was derived from the first one. I exported the first one and ran some analyses on it using a C++ tool I wrote, now I want to get the output back into ArcGIS. So the two layers will definitely overlap, it's just a matter of giving the second raster the right cell size/extent.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a method that works.

I used the Rescale tool in ArcToolbox to stretch each raster to the correct cell size.

Then I used the Shift tool to move it to the correct location by manually calculating how far it was from the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

@herbps10 It sounds like you are missing the projection information for your new raster file. You can use the [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm) tool to assign exactly the same coordinate system and projection information with your original file. You can find this information under the Properties for that dataset. Or you can load both layers in your ArcMap and when using the tool select the coordinate system information from the **Layers** list in the tool menu.